# AngularJS change injected global variable value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a constant `app.constant('DOCUMENT_ID', window.documentId || 1);` which I inject into services, controllers and directives.

I want to change `DOCUMENT_ID` to be a global variable, so that if I change `DOCUMENT_ID`'s value in controller, I want to get the changed value in all services and controllers in which `DOCUMENT_ID` was injected.

How can I use a global variable in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need global variable here (plus it's a bad practice). Just make use of the fact that objects are passed by references. For example you could use a service defined like this:

```
app.value('DOCUMENT', {
    ID: window.documentId || 1
});
```

Now, whenever you change `DOCUMENT.ID` anywhere, every part of the application will have updated version of ID. Just read it like object property.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Oay8IaLRnuCN2xkSuM69?p=preview

Comment: It should be the same also for `constant`, right? **EDIT:** tried in the plunker, it is.

Comment: Yes, you can also use constant. I just don't like to call a constant something that actually changes :)

Comment: Agreed, I was curious to verify if `constant` was truly a constant. Seems like it's not.